# Reloading part of classes inside running JVM

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, classloader

I have a CRM Web app running inside a Tomcat - single Servlet.

The whole object graph takes around 30 seconds to reload. That is too long for the whole app to be down in the production time.

Sometimes i have to make multiple updates in a matter of minutes on production. The changes are very small. Those cannot be abstracted into the front-end easily.

The reason i do not use a test enviroment is that the people deciding if the changes are good need to work on the production data.

Heap 2GB, running on 8yr old hardware. Live objects take up around 1.2GB, count around 500k objects constructed from an SQL DB.

**I want to reload only the front-end classes, and keep the object graph in the JVM.**

Possible solutions i came up:

- Split into two Servlets, and share context, let Tomcat manage the reloading of the front-end
- Manage my own reloading of the frontend classes with a custom classloader
- Implement the frontend in Javascript instead of in Java
- Any other/better solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: Could it make sense to use a separate and possibly persistent cache to keep your object graph outside the application? Thus you'd also be able to keep it in case of app crashes.

Comment: No, i want to have the object graph inside the JVM because it simplifies the business logic and other things. And i am afraid it will be too slow if i have the object graph outside the JVM. Many queries touch around tens of thousands of objects and need to run under a few seconds.

Comment: Well, I don't know what you're actually doing but most likely a proper (graph) database would be faster than you doing it yourself. Have a look at OrientDB, this might be what you need. In any case, splitting deployments into back and front end often is a good idea in order to decouple them (e.g. so you're able to independently update or scale them).

Comment: A graph database is not neccessary, no recursive relations.